# How to create an index on JSON filed in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I request your help to create an index for the **JSON** field as queried below on PostgreSQL. In my code, this field is using in the WHERE clause and it needs the index to speed up the query.

```
SELECT ((prime_data ->> 'prof'::text)::json) ->> 'find'::text AS prof_find 
FROM prof_table;
```

I have tried this gin index as the normal not working on this JSON field but no luck.

```
create index idx_prof_find 
   on prof_table using gin(((prime_data ->> 'prof'::text::json) ->> 'find'::text));
```

Comment: You query has no WHERE clause, so no index will help make that faster

Comment: `((prime_data ->> 'prof'::text)::json)` can be simplified to `(prime_data -> 'prof')` no need to first extract it as `text` and then cast it back it `json`. So the whole expression can be simplified to `prime_data -> 'prof' ->> 'find'` or `prime_data #>> '{prof,find}'`

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your recommendation. I would like to make it clear that this entire field value is using in the WHERE clause for a big query. That's the reason to create an index on this field 
"((prime_data ->> 'prof'::text)::json) ->> 'find'::text"

However, I didn't paste the complete query here as I just need to create an index on the above column.